# I have an error Undefined type 'Darryldecode\Cart\CartCondition'

Tags: cart, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmqjE.png)
i have an error "Undefined type 'Darryldecode\Cart\CartCondition'.". anyone can help me?

Comment: show some code .also have you installed that package

Comment: Does the specified folder exist? Do you have a typo error?

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP version must be 7.4 or higher or

```
use Darryldecode\Cart\CartCondition;

//.....
```